# How can i hide a back button from a MultiChoiceModeListener ActionMode?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm trying to hide a back `button` from a Contextmenu which appears when we long click on a `Listview` item. I don't know how to access to the actionMode menu's items, i tried `actionMode.getMenu().getItem()` but it doesn't show me the back `button` id. It seems that items is a default item from this menu, because i never inflate it.

Here the code :

```
        _m_list_view.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            _m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            _m_tweet_adaptateur.setChoiseMode(_m_list_view.getChoiceMode());
            _m_list_view.setItemChecked(i, true);
            return true;
        }
    });

    _m_list_view.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {

            updateActionModeTitle(actionMode);
            if(_m_list_view.getCheckedItemCount()==0) {
                _m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            mActionModeIsActive = true;
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_tweet, menu);
            actionMode.setCustomView(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.menu_select_tweet, null));
            updateActionModeTitle(actionMode);
            return(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //quand on appui sur ok dans le menu
                case R.id.item_select_multi_tweet:
                   //code when ok
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            //_m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            mActionModeIsActive = false;
            _m_tweet_adaptateur.setChoiseMode(_m_list_view.getChoiceMode());
            _m_list_view.setAdapter(_m_tweet_adaptateur);
        }
    });
```

What i want is just delete/hide this item :

[image: back item]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, i just needed to add an item `actionModeCloseButtonStyle` into styles.xml :

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/NoCloseButtonActionModeStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NoCloseButtonActionModeStyle">
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
</style>
```